# First double in C++ struct is automatically being shortened to two decimal places

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, formatting

Update:

As Pete Kirkham correctly pointed out println shortens the digits to two places. I updated my code with just plain old print and it still cuts those two off only. You have to put Serial.print(some_number, 7) if you want it to have 7 decimal places.

Thanks Pete

Original Post

I am pretty new to C++ and am writing an arduino GPS app and noticing one value keeps getting shortened to two decimal places while the other value in the struct does not.

Here is the struct declaration

```
    struct Poi {
      char name[30];
      double lat;
      double lng;
    };
```

Here is the actual struct instance:

```
    Poi poi_list[3] = {
      {"AK Plaza W",36.9905263,127.0847449}
      ,
      {"AK Plaza East",36.9905263,127.0861048}
      ,
      {"Ramen Place",36.9905263,127.0895004}
    }
```

Now when I try to see poi_list[0].lat or [1].lat or [2].lat all the values are 36.99 and it cuts off the rest, where the .lng value is always the entire number.

The entire file is on github [here](https://github.com/NickDamiano/parkometer/blob/master/gps_first_sketch.ino)

```
#include "TinyGPS++.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

SoftwareSerial serial_connection(10, 11); //RX=pin 10, TX=pin 11
TinyGPSPlus gps;//This is the GPS object that will pretty much do all the grunt work with the NMEA data
TinyGPSLocation loc;
const double EIFFEL_TOWER_LAT = 36.96070;
const double EIFFEL_TOWER_LNG = 127.05692;
struct Poi {
  char name[30];
  double lat;
  double lng;
};

Poi poi_list[13] = {
{"AK Plaza W",36.9905263,127.0847449}
,
{"AK Plaza East",36.9905263,127.0861048}
,
{"Ramen Place",36.9905263,127.0895004}
,
{"BX Center",36.9905263,127.0339894}
,
{"BX West",36.9905263,127.0350462}
,
{"Osan Chilis",36.9905263,127.0365375}
,
{"Work Main Gate",36.9905263,127.0219141}
,
{"Commissary",36.9905263,127.0024359}
,
{"PX Food Court",36.9905263,127.0002204}
,
{"PX Main entrance",36.9905263,126.9993058}
,
{"One Stop",36.9905263,127.0221126}
,
{"AMC",36.9905263,127.0425832}
,
{"Braii Republic",36.9905263,127.0446378}
};
int number_of_points = 13;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);//This opens up communications to the Serial monitor in the Arduino IDE
  serial_connection.begin(9600);//This opens up communications to the GPS
  Serial.println("GPS Start");//Just show to the monitor that the sketch has started 

}

void loop()
{
  while(serial_connection.available())//While there are characters to come from the GPS
  {
    gps.encode(serial_connection.read());//This feeds the serial NMEA data into the library one char at a time
  }
  if(gps.location.isUpdated())
  {
    for(int i=0;i<number_of_points;i++){
        Serial.print("Name: ");
        Serial.println(poi_list[i].name);
        Serial.print("Distance: ");
        Serial.print(calculate_distance(poi_list[i]));
    }
  }
}

float calculate_distance(Poi point){
  float distance = gps.distanceBetween(
    gps.location.lat(),
    gps.location.lng(),
    point.lat,
    point.lng);
    Serial.print("lat is ");
    Serial.print(point.lat);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("longitutde is ");
    Serial.print(point.lng);
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Did you try swapping the lat and long values?

Comment: Yes i accidentally put the values backwards initially and it cut of the long to 127.08

Comment: How do you "try to see" the value? I suspect the value is fine, but some ways of printing doubles default to a certain number of decimal places.

Comment: I posted all the code below my comment. The 4th line from the end is where I print it. I also have put the exact same line for the longitude and it prints fine. But I think it's not just the printing, the calculation is off. It's saying a place I know is 15 miles away is 2 miles away. and all points are roughly that distance even though they are not.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print), the output function `Serial.println()` will round floats to two digits after the coma:

> Serial.print(1.23456) gives "1.23"

If you want more detailed presentation, you have to specify the number of digits you want as second argument:

> Serial.println(1.23456, 4) gives "1.2346"

As Arduino's [float](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/float/) have only 6-7 digits of precision, you could go for

```
Serial.println(point.lat, 5);
```

Comment: This is a great catch but I updated my code above to show that it's still shortening only that first value and not the second. It's at the top of my post now.

Comment: @NickD are you sure? You print the second value and then the result without a space, and none of your longitudes is `127.0812345` but they are `127.08` to two decimal placeis and `12345` could come from what you're printing next.

Comment: @NickD is it possible that 12345 is the distance ?  because you print the long and then you return to the main loop, wich println() the result.  Other possibility is that the default precision is not handled correctly.  Try using fixed precision as shown above.

Comment: Wow you’re right it doesn’t match any other point. As far as the space goes it’s just because I’m using print instead of println that I added a space above to act like a line break. Something strange is happening because the point doesn’t match the hard coded points so I need to dig into some more tomorrow when I wake up(in Korea now). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I re-printed it with the argument stating i wanted 7 decimal places and both printed fine. Something weird that it printed one and not the other but oh well. As far as the inaccuracy I saw where things were all 3-4km away that's because my ruby script that translates my kml file to arduino c++ is somehow printing the same lattitude over and over. Something I did not catch. I feel dumb but thanks so much for your help and not making me feel like an idiot.